# How can i get user objects by id or userPrincipalName using Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get users from Active Directory using Graph API. For this i am using a list of user id's.

```
    String selectQuery = "id,mail,givenName,surname,displayName,businessPhones,department,assignedLicense";
    List<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<>();
    requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$select", selectQuery));
    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(new SimpleAuthProvider(accessToken)).buildClient();

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String userID : userList) {
        IUserRequest request = graphClient
                .users()
                .byId(userID)
                .buildRequest(requestOptions);
        users.add(request.get());
    }

    return users;
```

Using the code above i receive the input below.

```
[com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.User@5042e9c3, com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.User@1c9fc2e2]
```

I would like to receive user resource fields(such as mail, givenName, surname, displayName, businessPhones etc.) for users which i am searching. I used a sample query in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users%2F925e59ce-4e2e-40b0-9d2c-f7a6535f4ec0&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com). But i fail to get multiple users with java sdk. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and you have got the users.

You need to poll `users` and get their corresponding attributes, like this:

```
for (User user : users) {
    System.out.println("id:" + user.id + " mail:" + user.mail + " displayName:" + user.displayName);
}
```